# Generating json file from text file in Python and removing unnecessary braces

Tags: python, json, loops

Basically I'm generating a json Terraform file from a text file, but I can't get it to format in the correct way:

I want the finished Terraform file to look like this:

```
{
  "resource": {
    "aws_route53_record": {

      "analytics": {
        "name": "analytics",
        "records": ["1.2.3.4"],
        "ttl": "1800",
        "type": "A"
      },

      "analytics-test": {
        "name": "analytics-test",
        "records": ["1.2.3.4"],
        "ttl": "300",
        "type": "A"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which is the format Terraform requires to parse json.

So I load the text file in Python, and iterate over each line producing a list of lists that look like so:

```
records = [["analytics", "1.2.3.4", "1800", "A"],["analytics-test", "1.2.3.4", "300", "A"]]
```

My code to generate the file at the moment looks like this

I create a dict placeholder containing top level variable like so:

```
json_object = {'resource': {'aws_route53_record': None}}
```

Then I look through records and assign the appropriate values:

```
for each_list in data:
    terrarecord = {
        each_list[0]:{
            "name": each_list[0],
            "type": each_list[2],
            "ttl": each_list[1],
            "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
        }
    }

record_holder.append(terrarecord)
```

The `record_holder` object is an empty list that I then use to fill in the `json_objects` like so:

`json_object['resource']['aws_route53_record'] = record_holder`

What this gives me in the finished file is:

```
    {
    "resource": {
        "aws_route53_record": [{
            "analytics": {
                "ttl": "1800",
                "records": ["173.194.245.129"],
                "name": "analytics",
                "type": "A"
            }
        }, {
            "analytics-test": {
                "ttl": "300",
                "records": ["130.211.89.168"],
                "name": "analytics-test",
                "type": "A"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

So would there be an easier way to do this without adding the extra `[]` and `{}`s that my little loop does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating the intermediate list when you want the dictionary?

```
terrarecord = {}
for each_list in data:
    terrarecord[each_list[0]] = {
        "name": each_list[0],
        "type": each_list[2],
        "ttl": each_list[1],
        "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
    }
}

json_object['resource']['aws_route53_record'] = terrarecord
```

Comment: My stupidity knows no bounds. Thanks for pointing this out to me. I think I become lost in my own code